# Не работает style.css в теме wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

тема работает, другие css и js скрипты подгружаются, а при попытке добавить свой стиль в style.css он не реагирует на сайт. В чем может быть ошибка?

[исходный код][1]
[1]: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1EpNMiiVK5d3GgzzepDQqFVGyFr3rzv3x?usp=drive_link

Comment: Код нужно показывать в вопросе. Но если ты хочешь показать  файл стилей - он тут не нужен.  Показывай как его подключаешь. Или рассказывай куда и как  добавляешь свои стили (в какой style.css).

Comment: @SeVlad вангую не глядя: тема своя, wp_enqueue_style( ... '...style.css' ); не выполнен. Типичная ошибка.

Comment: @SeVlad так и есть. Зашел на GDrive и увидел ровно то, о чем написал. :)

Comment: @KAGGDesign я тоже это подозревал (потому ж и написал про подключение), но лазить по гуглодискам мне лениво :)